# Trying to get rid of title bar for all activities

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get rid of the title bar in every activity for my app, but it is crashing on startup. I only modified the manifest and did not touch any onCeate() methods. Relevant manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UpgradeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upgrade"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StatsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_stats"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PrestiegeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_prestiege"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

LogCat: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.company/com.example.company.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
</style>
```

In your manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

and in your activity extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: Just to add to this answer, to easily add this theme to all activities, just put the `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"` in your `<application>`.