# Getting rid of the title bar when using android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout without affecting rendering of sample layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got the most recent version of Android Studio. After I made a new application with it using a Blank Activity, I got 2 layouts for the MainActivity(or MyActivity as its referred to in the official tutorial). There seems to be a activity_my.xml which includes content_my.xml.

I wanted to get rid of the title bar only, so I tried the following: [Trying to get rid of title bar for all activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728463/trying-to-get-rid-of-title-bar-for-all-activities)

Now activity_my.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_my" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

v21/styles.xml has:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    </style>
```

That did not work.

When I go to design view for activity_my.xml, I still see the title bar. Then I removed the XML in section

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> ...  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and the bar is finally gone!!

BUT now if go to content_my.xml and go to its Design view, I get a huge rendering error:

```
     Rendering Problems 

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE 

 Exception Details 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) 

Copy stack to clipboard  

The surrounding layout (@layout/activity_my) did not actually include this layout. Remove tools:showIn=... from the root tag.
```

So how do I fix the last error. It seems I have to somehow keep this android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout XML around but that interferes with my title bar free UI :(

NOTE: activity_my.xml still does include content_my.xml as I did not delete the following line from it: include layout="@layout/content_my"

So content_my.xml should continue to render properly.

---

Here my build.gradle for Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got it.

It seems styles.xml (not v21/styles.xml) must have this appended to it:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Then AndroidManifest.xml should have:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
...
```

Then I can safely remove the part:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> ...</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

from activity_my.xml

This allows both activity_my.xml and content_my.xml to render again without title bar in MainActivity.xml

The rendering in the device was always without title bar(as expected) and still is, irrespective of the design library error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear; Make sure that you are extending the `AppCompatActivity` .

Comment: I am in fact. The sample application generated by Android Studio does that for the MainActivity.

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion ? if it's beneath 21 then please share your default styles.xml file.

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 23. Just added the build.gradle file. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Sorry for asking for too many details but I need to know whether you're running your app on a Lollipop device or not.

Comment: The Android version is 4.4.4 KTU84P Irrespective of the device though, the rendering library should not error out.

Comment: OK so you are targeting API 23 but running on API 19 or 20... show me your pre-Lollipop styles.xml file.